# It is possible to extract data from iframe and send them via ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe

I create a simple link generator but I have a little problem.

Now it works like this:
Url adress => [post to server and parsing page via curl] => Direct links.

The problem is that, links are assigned to the server ip so user can not use them.
So I came up with the idea to extract data from iframe by user browser and use ajax to send them to the server. 
Something like that is at all possible?

Comment: i don't think that this will work with JS, read about cross-domain policy, if the iframe is on the same domain, yes, but on different i think not.

Comment: What a pity! anyway thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible when the iframe is on the domain.

Using `html5` you have the sandbox option `allow-same-origin` but it's not available in most browsers.

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_sandbox.asp